# If date is less than today do not display

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am searching for a data by php in mysql database with

```
id   name   empcode        doj     date of retirement
1     xyz     123456   12/02/1955    12/02/1985      //its an example purpose only
2     abc     254525   05/02/1955    12/02/1989
3     def     055455   10/02/1945    12/02/1552
4     ijk     875545   12/02/1955    12/02/1962
```

when I search with name it should check the name as well as the employee is retired or not with current date. display no employee with this result.

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newdb
            WHERE (`EMPCODE` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`NAME` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: 1. Do not use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. 2. We don't know which column says that "employee is retired" 3. Avoid showing MySQL errors to the user

Comment: So add an extra check to your WHERE clause - what datatype are your dates?

Comment: If question does not contain question do not display

Comment: Er, yes remove error messages from production but for development purposes, I think the error messages are pretty much essential!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to store the date in your database as  int(11) and store dates in unix timestamp format. then you can easily manipulate the date.